# How do I plot an "indefite-sum" function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

My function is just a simple summation from -inf to inf: f(x) = sum(pi * exp(-x+2pi*j), j = -inf to in);

I tried doing this, but got error saying "A numeric or double convertible argument is expected"

```
x = linspace(-7, 7, 1000);
h = 10; 
syms j; 
v_hat = symsum(pi * exp(x + 2*pi*j),-inf, inf); %v_hat is a function of x: v_hat(x)
plot(x, v_hat);
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing an input argument to `symsum`, plus a closing bracket on the right. Moreover do you really want to compute the sum relatively to `j` and not `x` ?

Comment: yes, j is the count variable and v_hat is a function of x

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, what matlab version do you use. I use 2014b. However, are you trying to do a function series, you may want to have `x` as a sym. `syms x,j; v_hat = symsum(pi * exp(x + 2*pi*j),j,-inf, inf);`. This gives nan though for this function. You may have to do some mathematical tricks to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your code programming-wise, but there is a fatal mathematical flaw -- the sum is infinite for every x. Note that it's just sum of exp(2*pi*j) multiplied by pi*exp(x). The values exp(2*pi*j) are large when j is positive, and you try to add infinitely many of them...

When I change the formula to a series that actually converges, the code works, although it takes a long while.

```
x = linspace(-7, 7, 1000);
h = 10; 
syms j; 
v_hat = symsum(pi * exp(-abs(x+ 2*pi*j/h) ),-inf, inf);
plot(x, v_hat);
```

[image: prettylong]

Note that the quality isn't great despite using 1000 data points.  You will get better quality *much* faster by abandoning symbolic sum. The contribution of the terms with abs(j)>100 is tiny here, so drop them and use numeric sum over the rest.

```
h = 10; 
x = linspace(-7,7,10000);
[X,j] = meshgrid(x, -100:100);
v_hat = sum(pi * exp(-abs(X+ 2*pi*j/h) ), 1);
plot(x, v_hat);
```

[image: numeric]

Also, realize that the function is periodic with period 2*pi/h. So you can  plot 
one or two periods of the function, and imagine the rest.

```
h = 10; 
x = linspace(-2*pi/h, 2*pi/h, 101);
syms j;
v_hat = symsum(pi * exp(-abs(x+ 2*pi*j/h) ),-inf, inf); 
plot(x, v_hat);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Woodface. Actually, my function is $v_hat = symsum(pi * exp(-abs(x+2*pi*j/h)), -inf, inf)$ so it does converge, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: YES! Mine took forever too! So it's not just my machine then.